# Changing document title back with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have some event which would change the document title using javascript.

```
    $('.someclass').click(function(){
        document.title = "Some new title"; 
    });
```

Now that I've renamed the document title, how do I revert it back to what it was originally? The text that actually appears between the `<title>` tags in the html document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would save the original title before you change it:

```
var originalTitle = document.title;

$('.someclass').click(function(){
    document.title = "Some new title"; 
});

$('.changeBack').click(function() {
    document.title = originalTitle;
});
```

(Obviously you don't have to change it back within any particular click handler, the code I've shown is just an example.)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I've been thinking too hard. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to toggle you could also do it like this:

```
// saving the titles in an object
var title = {
    oldTitle: document.title,
    newTitle: "This is the new title"
};
var oldTitle = true; // flag set to true initially

// Toggling on click
$('.someClass').on('click', function(){
    // Check the flag and set the value accordingly
    if(oldTitle){
        document.title = title.newTitle;
        oldTitle = false;
    } else {
        document.title = title.oldTitle;
        oldTitle = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle between 2 different titles you could do something like this.

```
var arr = ["oldtitle", "newtitle"], i = 0;
$('.someclass').on("click", function(){
    document.title = arr[i++%2]
});
```